# Covariant derivative of Weyl spinor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, spinors

What is the expression for the covariant derivative of a Weyl spinor?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu$ be a spacetime index, $a,b$ be an internal space indices and $\alpha,\beta$ be spinor indices. The covariant derivative has the form:
$$
\nabla_\mu \psi_\alpha = \partial_\mu \psi_\alpha + \frac{1}{4}\, \omega_{\mu ab} (\sigma^{ab})_\alpha{}^\beta \psi_\beta
$$
where
$$
\sigma^{ab} = \frac{1}{4} [ \sigma^a {\bar \sigma}^b - \sigma^b {\bar \sigma}^a ] 
$$
with
$$
\sigma^a = ( I_{2\times2} , \sigma_1 , \sigma_2 , \sigma_3 ) , \qquad {\bar \sigma}^a  = ( -I_{2\times2} , \sigma_1 , \sigma_2 , \sigma_3 ) . 
$$
The signs and factors of $2$ and $4$ are all convention based and I'm not certain I have the right factors in this answer. Your homework is to figure out the right factors.

HINT: With the right factors, we must have
$$
[ \nabla_\mu , \nabla_\nu ] \psi_\alpha = \# R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} e^\rho_c e^\sigma_d ( \sigma^{cd} )_\alpha{}^\beta \psi_\beta
$$

Comment: Thanks! I am supposed to follow the convention of Wess and Bagger. Your definition of $\sigma^{ab}$ matches that of Wess & Bagger (eq. A.14). But I'm not sure how to check if the factor of $\frac14$ in your first equation matches with the convention of Wess and Bagger.

There is a definition of the covariant derivative below eq. (19.20). But that uses $\omega_{\mu\alpha}{}^{\beta}$. Not sure what factor of 2 has been used in the definition of $\omega_{\mu\alpha}{}^{\beta}$ in terms of $\omega_{\mu a b}(\sigma^{ab})_\alpha{}^\beta$. Any suggestion how to check?

Comment: @vyali - answer edited!

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: What is # supposed to be in the hint equation?

Comment: that is again dependent on your conventions for $\sigma^{ab}$. If I remember correctly, the proper formula is $[ \nabla_\mu , \nabla_\nu ] \psi_\alpha = R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} e^\rho_c e^\sigma_d ( \Sigma^{cd} )_\alpha{}^{\beta} \psi_\beta$ where $\Sigma^{ab}$ is a (spinor) representation of the Lorentz algebra which is normalized to satisfy $[\Sigma_{ab} , \Sigma_{cd} ] = i ( \eta_{ac} \Sigma_{bd} - a \leftrightarrow b ) - c \leftrightarrow d$. Using the properties of $\sigma^{ab}$ you should be able to work out how this is related to the $\Sigma_{ab} = \# \sigma_{ab}$